# A .mp4 converter with command line support?

Tags: command-line, video-conversion, mp4

I would like to find an application that I can use to convert any video format in .mp4 or .ogg from the command line.

I don't mind it cost money as long it worth it.

Which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) may meet [your needs](http://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php).

Comment: This one looks exactly like what I need. Let me study it further.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could take a look at [Avidemux](http://avidemux.berlios.de/), it is multiplatform, supports many formats (included mp4) and supports [command line interface](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using:command_line_usage). There is also a good [scripting engine](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=using:scripting) if you need more powerful usage.

Comment: Nice, but it looks like an overkill :D

Comment: @vtortola : maybe (probably ;) ) overkill, but you wanted to convert `any video format`, and avidemux can convert almost every format...

Answer (score 1):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) is "A complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video."

It is used in almost every open source projects nowadays and is included in almost every Linux distro. It also has Windows versions

Answer (score 0):

*VLC Media Player* provides support for video conversion. Though it is not as powerful as dedicated tools like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr), it is commonly installed in most personal computers (i.e. you don't have to download software) and supports a [plethora](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/features.html) of video input formats. To use *VLC* for your purpose, see the [*VLC* Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode/).

An example command on Windows may be this:

```
"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\vlc.exe" --no-repeat --no-loop -vvv "C:\Movies\my_video.avi" --sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:standard{access=file,mux=ts,dst="C:\my_video_output.mpg"}
```

Various other programs can also be used.